# How to debug moor: getting no such table error

Tags: flutter, flutter-moor

I'm inserting data to my database and got the following error...

```
flutter: Moor: Sent INSERT INTO add_cash (name, amount, date, frequency, is_deleted) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?) with args [income, 100000, 1573102800, once, 0]
```

Does the question marks mean that the data wasn't inserted into the database

Here is the button that sends data to database

```
CupertinoButton.filled(
  onPressed: () {
    scakey.currentState.onItemTapped(1);
    createAddCash();
  },
  child: Text('ADD CASH'),
),
```

```
void createAddCash() async {
  final database = Provider.of<AppDatabase>(context);
  final task = AddCashData(
      name: oneController.text,
      amount: int.parse(twoController.text),
      date: selectedDate,
      frequency: selectedItem,
      isDeleted: false);
  database.insertAddCash(task);
}
```

Here is my database

```
class AddCash extends Table {
  IntColumn get id => integer().autoIncrement()();
  TextColumn get name => text()();
  IntColumn get amount => integer()();
  DateTimeColumn get date => dateTime()();
  TextColumn get frequency => text()();
  BoolColumn get isDeleted => boolean()();
}


@UseMoor(tables: [AddCash])
class AppDatabase extends _$AppDatabase {
  AppDatabase()
      // Specify the location of the database file
      : super(
          (FlutterQueryExecutor.inDatabaseFolder(
            path: 'db.sqlite',
            // Good for debugging - prints SQL in the console
            logStatements: true,
          )),
        );
  @override
  int get schemaVersion => 1;

  Future insertAddCash(AddCashData addCashData) =>
      into(addCash).insert(addCashData);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does the question marks mean that the data wasn't inserted into the
>   database

No, it is not an error message. The question mark indicate the parameter that will be stored to the databse. I would suggest you add `try-catch`  between your code, so you can check what is the error.

```
  try {
    final task = AddCashData(...);
    database.insertAddCash(task);
   } catch (e) {
    print(e.toStirng()); // this line will be printed if there is any errors 
   }
```